# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, in_execute_child raise child_exception

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I am new to Python and Linux, I am getting an error

```
File "usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py, line 1335, in_execute_child
=======
 raise child_exception" 
=======
 OSERROR: [Error 2] No Such File or Directory
=======
```

This image shows the commands and error that I am facing:

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code in your post?

Comment: What is `apimonitor.py`?